# How to get all the records from Table1 and matching ones from Table2 in case no match found using Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I have a query

```
declare @NOCAppId int = 1
Select doc.DocId, doc.DocName,subDoc.NOCAppId,
subDoc.SDocId,  subDoc.Status
 FROM NOCDocument doc
 join NOCSubmittedDoc subDoc
 on doc.DocId = subDoc.DocId
 WHERE subDoc.NOCAppId = @NOCAppId
OR @NOCAppId IS NULL
```

### Here is my first table

```
DocId  DocName
1      T1
2      T2
3      T3
4      T4
5      T5
```

### Here is my second table

```
SDocId  Status        DocId   NOCAppId   DocName
1       NotSubmitted    1     1          T1
2       Submitted       2     1          T2
3       NotSubmitted    3     1          T3
4       NotRequired     4     1          T4
5       Submitted       5     1          T5
6       NotRequired     1     2          T1
7       NotRequired     2     2          T3
8       NotRequired     3     2          T3
9       NotRequired     4     2          T4
10      NotRequired     5     2          T5
```

Now if I send DocId as Null I want the result to be like below if I have a record for a DocId in Table2

```
SDocId  Status        DocId   NOCAppId   DocName
1       NotSubmitted    1     1          T1
2       Submitted       2     1          T2
3       NotSubmitted    3     1          T3
4       NotRequired     4     1          T4
5       Submitted       5     1          T5
```

If there is no matching row in table2 w.r.t NOCAppId then I want the result to be like

```
SDocId  Status        DocId   NOCAppId   DocName
NULL    NotSubmitted    1     NULL          T1
NULL    Submitted       2     NULL          T2
NULL    NotSubmitted    3     NULL          T3
NULL    NotRequired     4     NULL          T4
NULL    Submitted       5     NULL          T5
```

Thanks

Comment: In your second table sample data, I dont see any `NOCAppId` as `null`. If it is there, then please add it to sample data.

Comment: Use outer joins instead (left, right full outer) of inner? Instead of `join NOCSubmittedDoc subDoc` use `LEFT JOIN  NOCSubmittedDoc subDoc` ?

Comment: @Utsav that is how it looks like.

Comment: @xQbert thxs for the suggestion. Already tried but doesn't work.

Comment: It would, move the where clause to the join as well change `WHERE subDoc.NOCAppId = @NOCAppId
OR @NOCAppId IS NULL` to `and subDoc.NOCAppId = @NOCAppId
OR @NOCAppId IS NULL` as the left join is being negated by the where cluase, making the left join an inner.

Comment: @xQbert let me give a handy on that. Thx.:)

Comment: Nm that will not work I just re-read what you're doing and have to rebuild more of it.

Comment: @xQBert works good in case If I have a record with NOCAppId=1 and  even 2 in Table2. Can u plz tell me if user pass NOCAppId which doesnot exist in table2 and how to show the output as described in my question.  Your answer looked good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make it a LEFT join
2. Move the where clause to the join as it is negating the outer join (making it an inner as all the NULL values generated by the left join would be excluded)
3. Eliminate the null check, it's not needed based on your data.
4. Add case statement to handle null and a coalesce on join.  It looks like even when it's "Null" you want to return the status of those records NocAppId = 1.... If that's not true, then explain how you pick "status" when NoCAppID is null.

.

```
SELECT case when @NoCAppID is null then NULL else SDocID end as SDocID
    , Status
    , DocID
    , case when @NoCAppID is null then NULL else NoCAppID end as NocAppID
    , DocName
FROM NOCDocument doc
  on Sub1.DocID = Doc.DocID
LEFT JOIN NOCSubmittedDoc subDoc
 on doc.DocId = subDoc.DocId
 and (subDoc.NoCAppId = coalesce(@NoCAppId,1))  
--It appears to me you want the status when nocAppID is 1 even if null is passed in, but 
--you want Null values to appear in NoCAppID, and SDocID in the select, 
--which is handled by a case statement  So coalesce here and case in the select!
```